# QGIS Python Script - Routing along Waypoints

Tags: qgis, python, routing

I used Anita Graser's script [point_layer_to_route.py](https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-Processing-tools/blob/master/2.4/scripts/point_layer_to_route.py) which worked like a charm until I updated to 2.6. With QGIS 2.6 I always get objects without any features. Can anybody tell me if he/she had the same issues?

Comment: @carycorreia It makes no sense to "hijack" an old closed question. Nobody will see and answer it. Please open a new thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me in QGIS 2.6 with Processing 2.6 (on Win7) and the test data Spatialite file from the repository.

If you are using different data, please share it. Check if network and points are in the same CRS.

Comment: Thanks, for looking at it! It indeed must have been a corrupt file - after creating a new file and using that everything was ok again!

Answer (score 1):

That script won't work in the latest version of QGIS as the  Processing framework has been reworked and some scripts may have been broken.

Maybe you will be lucky, you could try to change line 17 (as below):

```
from processing.tools.vector import VectorWriter
```

Comment: @Irssvt, this will cause an error.

Comment: It seems as if only when my points come from SQLite file format I'm having issues. With shp-files everythings ok..

Comment: That is very strange or you have a different processing version. With the latest version of processing plugin (2.6 or master) that script throws an error ```ImportError: No module named VectorWriter``` as the writer module has been moved from ```core``` to ```tools.vector```. At the least this is what is happening to me. I am assuming you are trying with the processing plugin version 2.2.0-2 found in the official repository of QGIS.

Comment: Strange, I'm using Processing 2.6 and both the import line you pasted as well as the import line in my scipts work fine without errors ... Maybe time to test on a fresh install ...

Comment: Yeah, it is odd, what is the output of ```qgis.utils.pluginMetadata('processing', 'version')``` by pyqgis console?

Comment: Fyi, that returns ```u'2.6'```.